# Getting json data before loading bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get json data and save them in local storage using angularjs but this error "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" appears in inspect element any help ?!!

```
function getData($http,callback){
        //callback();
        $http.get(server + "/CrewServices/adminConsole/adminData")
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    app.value('adminData', data);
                    var Roles=unique(data.roles);
                    localStorage.setItem("currLoggedUSer", data.userName);
                    localStorage.setItem("currLoggedUSerRoles", Roles);
                    angular.forEach(data.airlines, function (key) {
                        if( key == 0 && localStorage.getItem("selectedAirline") == null ){
                            localStorage.setItem("selectedAirline", data.airlines[key].airline);
                            localStorage.setItem("selectedAirlineApiKey", data.airlines[key].key);
                        }
                    });
                    callback();
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // log error
                });
    }
```

Comment: Angular would inject the $http service - since the $http variable is undefined you probably have an issue with loading angular. Make sure you have included script tags to add angular in your html page and that this code is in an angular controller or service etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $http into your controller.  [Here's more info in the Angular documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope, $interval, $http){

    $interval(function($scope, $http){

        $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){

        });
    },5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before bootstrap, you need to get hold of injector and get $http service manually.

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
    var $http = initInjector.get("$http");
    $http.get
```